# MVC 3 DropDownListFor ModelState.IsValid is False

Tags: guid, html.dropdownlistfor

In the view .cshtml page:

```
    @{var items = new SelectList(Model.Rooms, "RoomGUID", "FullName");}
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Request.Room, @items)
```

In the ViewModel .cs page:

```
    public class NewRequestView
        {
            public IEnumerable<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
            public Request Request { get; set; }
        }
```

In the Controller . cs page:

```
    NewRequestView nrv = new NewRequestView();
        nrv.Request = r;
        nrv.Rooms = db.Rooms;

        return View(nrv);
```

The data is in the ModelState.Value.AttemptedValue, but the ModelState.ISValid is false. Any idea? Beacause it is returnning the GUID not the object.

Answer (score 0):

By putting this line in your code and setting a breakpoint on it, you can get a list of your validation errors in the Watch window:

```
var x = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
```